# How to update priority of an entry in a PriorityQueue?

Tags: python, priority-queue

I am using

```
from queue import PriorityQueue
pq = PriorityQueue()
pq.put((3, "Harry"))
pq.put((4, "Harry"))
pq.put((2, "Mary"))
```

This now creates two entries of "Harry". Am I supposed to remove all keys one by one (for searching) and then do a put to update the value?

Comment: Which "Harry" do you want to update? They're already "sorted" by the order in which they were enqueued.

Comment: I actually only wanted to have one "Harry" in the priority queue whose priority I wanted to update from 3 to 4. The "put" function call creates two "Harry"s instead of updating the first "Harry".

Comment: I don't think `PriorityQueue` supports deleting items or changing priorities.

Comment: By the way, unless you're using this queue specifically as a channel to send messages from producer threads to consumer threads, you should probably use `heapq` instead. The `queue` module is specifically intended for use as an inter-thread message passing system, and it has design choices and overhead that don't make sense for other uses.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8706363/56778 explains how to delete in a heap. Neither Python's `PriorityQueue` nor `heapq` gives you the access to the backing array that is required to make this happen.

Comment: Can't you loop though the queue till you find the entry with "Harry", change its priority to a small number, add and then delete a bogus value, that way Harry will appear on the from of the queue and you can remove it with get.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with using a custom solution, here is a `PriorityQueue` that I implemented, and showcased with the Dijkstra algorithm: https://github.com/denizetkar/priority-queue

Answer (score 0):

The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue-objects) for `PriorityQueue` doesn't have a direct method to search a value inside `Queue` objects.

Edit: The `PriorityQueue` is implemented as a [binary heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823905/how-to-iterate-over-a-priority-queue-in-python/25825860#25825860) so changing the priority in the elements it won't update the binary tree as [Jim Mischel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61434738/how-to-update-priority-of-an-entry-in-a-priorityqueue/61435030#comment108738083_61435030) said:

> Changing the node's priority results in a potentially invalid heap.

Comment: Your code results in a `PriorityQueue` with the contents: `(1, 'Harry'), (2, 'Mary'), (3, 'Harry')` — so doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Another thing is that although the `queue` attribute isn't marked private, I don't think using it is part the public interface to a `PriorityQueue` (or regular `Queue` for that matter).

Comment: I didn't know that he only wanted unique values in the `PriorityQueue`, the code works only to change the priority of an item, using a `set` to be sure that there are unique elements it will be a better approach.

Comment: The code when I wrote my comment doesn't change the priority of an item. It also seems counterproductive to do a linear search, O(n), through a priority queue.

Comment: I changed the code with the new information, I agree with you about O(n) complexity, a better approach it will be to search using the iformation about the [binary heap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25825860/8425653)

Comment: Your `change_priority_of' method won't work. If the node you changed the priority of is not on the same branch of the tree the new "Dummy" node is added to, then it won't be affected by adding and removing a node. Changing the node's priority results in a potentially invalid heap. Any further operations on that heap have the potential of breaking.

Comment: Your totally right, I have not seen the error with the heap, I will upload my answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8706363/56778 explains how to delete in a heap. Neither Python's `PriorityQueue` nor `heapq` give you the access to the backing array that is required to make this happen.